# Programmatically update sharepoint 2013 "Created By", "Modified By" item fields

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

Can I update these fields dynamically?

```
SPFile file = ds.Files.Add(ds.Url + @"\" + record.Name, data, true);
file.Item["Created_x0020_By"] = "test";
file.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author] = "testauthor";
file.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Editor] = "test editor";
file.Item.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the Author and Editor using String...
You need to pass as SPUser.
For example u want to save current user use 
`SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser` 
If you want to save as other user please use

```
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser("domain\\username"); 
file.item["Author"] = user
```

Comment: although i agree this is the best way to go,   if your running a farm linked to active directory you should actually be able to drop a "Domain\Username" string into it and it will resolve the user from there.